# Change scutil HostName to ComputerName on osx

Tags: linux, macos, networking, dns

I have about 100 users with Mac Books on which I have admin access.
I have set up a `dnsmasq` DNS-Server on a Linux box that has the Domain "schoolnet".
Now I have the problem, that all Mac Books have a ComputerName and a LocalHostName (which is the same as ComputerName but with "-" instead of space), but no HostName defined.

On the network they all register with the hostname "localhost" I would like them to have the same HostName as their LocalHostName.

How could I achieve that with a `scutil` command I could send to them?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done rather easily, programatically.

```
COMPUTERNAME="$(scutil --get LocalHostName)" && scutil --set HostName $COMPUTERNAME
```

Here we set COMPUTERNAME variable to the value contained in LocalHostName, and sets the HostName accordingly.